# Text-indent set with javascript has double value in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, text-indent

I have some javascript that calculates a value and applies it as a text-indent to a select list. This works fine cross browser and device except on firefox (im using the latest version).

With firebug I can see the correct text indent pixel value is being applied as an inline style, however the results is double the indentation width.

If I disable the text indent and apply the same pixel value as a left padding I can see its correct. If I disable javascript and apply the same text-indent with normal CSS it also works fine. Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code, and consider a working example with http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I cant put my actual code online. Ive tried to recreate the issue here but its not happening http://jsfiddle.net/KVW2x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason applying the text-indent to the div containing the select list works fine.